# Rank only values in a column that are numbers

Tags: excel

I have several columns that I would like to derive a ranking for. The original, unranked values are, for instance:

```
A    B
1    2
3    5
6    4
5    #N/A
4    0.1
```

The ranking would be, through the function =RANK(A*,A:A,0):

```
A    B
5    3  
4    1
1    2
2    #N/A
3    4
```

If the value in the same row in column B is #N/A, then I would like to exclude the value in the same row from column A, i.e., it should omit the value "5" from the original column and then just rank the remaining 4 values. The result should be:

```
A    B
4    3  
3    1
1    2
#N/A #N/A
2    4
```

I tried several if statements, but they always fail to remove the values from the array against which they are ranked.

How can I calculate the rank in column a with the same amount of values as column B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add one column where you can remove that number with `IF="#N/A"`first then you can sort the new list with `=RANG.EQ(C1;C:C)`, but I am assuming you have that error in the column.

If you import any number you could add the `IF` when u import the numbers.

Hope that helps

Comment: That won't be possible because I need to calculate correlations of the rank the first column with 11,000 other columns.

Comment: Put in any changes if you come up with any. Good it helped some even though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Krib. I ended up inserting some helper rows with the intermediate step, per your suggestion. I was hoping to do it in one go. Anyway, task accomplished, albeit less elegantly than I wished.